# Third party codecs in AV Foundation

Tags: macos, avfoundation, foundation

I was under the impression that AV Foundation doesn't support third-party codecs. If I try to open an Avid DNxHD QuickTime movie in my application it doesn't work, as expected.

However, if I open a DNxHD movie in QuickTime Player X (which also uses AVF) it opens and plays back fine and even says it's a DNxHD in the Info window.

Does anyone know how Apple is achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that QuickTime Player X is built on QT X, not on top of AVF. In fact, I think it uses (something like) QTKit, which will launch a 32-bit proxy process if necessary to open files that are only supported by 32-bit codecs.

You can access QT X via the QTKit framework, if you specify the 'playback only' attribute when you open the file, but then you can only play it back (as the flag suggests!). Even enumerating the number of tracks will fail. If you don't specify playback-only, then you are limited to QT7 components, accessed via a 32-bit proxy if your app is 64-bit.

Comment: This is correct on 10.6 but on 10.7+ it uses AVF. But I've since discovered the answer to my question - it launches a 32-bit helper process called LegacyMediaBridge. This appears to be a private framework so it's likely that any app trying to use it will be rejected from the app store, so I think I will revert to QTKit for unsupported codecs.

Comment: QT Player is AVFoundation based since 10.9 rather than 10.7.